# Find Numerals in Text and insert vbCr immediately before Numerals

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a word document with numerical references spread throughout the body of my text.  For example "*text string 1*" ###:### "*text string 2*".  Note the colon in the middle of the numberical reference.  The numerical references may range from 1-999 on either side of the colon, but every reference has at least one number on each side of the colon with no more than 3 numbers on either side.

I need a routine that scans the entire document, identifies each numeral reference and then enters a carriage return BEFORE the numerical reference.... so every numerical reference would start a paragraph in the document.  To illustrate this, the example above would be transformed to...

"Text string 1"

"###:###" "Text String 2"

I've tried modifying a Find/Replace operation to do this (to the point I'm going cross eyed) but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using **RegExp** is a bit complicated here as long as there is `Find-Replace` feature in MS Word. Try with this code:

```
Sub Find_Replace_Macro()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find

        .Text = "([ ])([0-9]{1;3}:[0-9]{1;3})"    'solution for non-English version of MS-Word
        .Text = "([ ])([0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3})"    'solution for English version of MS-Word
        .Replacement.Text = "^13\2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: KazJaw - thanks for he reply --- I copied your text into the VB editor but when I run the macro I get "The Find What text contains a Pattern match expression which is not valid"..... any ideas?

Comment: which version of MS Office you have?

Comment: try to replace semicolons into commas in pattern to this one: `"([ ])([0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3})"` as I added to my answer...

Comment: I have Word 2010 --- and that fixed it.  I replaced the semicolon's with commas as you suggested.  THANK YOU!

Comment: AFAIK you can generalise this by using the character in Application.International(wdListSeparator).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple Regular Expression Replace Function...

```
Sub TestSub()
Dim StrText

StrText = "Blajdflajdflaj 123:133 lajdflkaj123:343 alkdjflakjd 444:78 alkjdlfajkdlksjalk"

Debug.Print AddNewLine(StrText)
End Sub

Function AddNewLine(strInput)
Dim objRegEx
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\d{1,3}\:\d{1,3}"
    'Remove one of the vbCrLf's if you only want a single New Line
AddNewLine = objRegEx.Replace(strInput, vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "$&")
End Function
```

The above routine will create the below output:

> Blajdflajdflaj
>
> 123:133 lajdflkaj
>
> 123:343 alkdjflakjd
>
> 444:78 alkjdlfajkdlksjalk

If your working with a MS Word Document, you can test with:

```
StrText = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
```

For some extra reading on Substitutions in Regular Expressions please see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx

Comment: B Hart - thanks for the reply.  I set StrText = activedocument.range.text though and it isn't working.  How do I set the contents of the document to equal StrText??  The code isn't error'ing out... it just isn't doing anything?

Comment: @AdamMcClung - If your working with MS Word, Try ActiveDocument.Content.Text - If your not working with Word, what are you trying to read?